# Tensorflow gradients are always zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

Tensorflow gradients are always zero with respect to conv layers that are after first conv layer. I've tried different ways to check that but gradients are always zero! Here is the small reproducible code that can be run to check that.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import random
import tflearn
batch_size = 100
start = 0
end = batch_size
learning_rate = 0.000001
num_classes = 4
time_steps = 4
embedding = 2
step = 1
_units = 500
num_of_filters = 1000

train_set_x = [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]]
train_set_y = [0,1]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,time_steps,embedding])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])


x = tf.expand_dims(X,3)

filter_shape = [1, embedding, 1, num_of_filters]
conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights1" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
normalize = conv + conv_biases
tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

filter_shape2 = [1, 1, 1, num_of_filters]
conv_weights2 = tf.get_variable("conv_weights2" , filter_shape2, tf.float32, tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
conv_biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
normalize2 = conv2 + conv_biases2
tf_normalize2 = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize2)
relu2 = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize2)
pooling2 = tf.reduce_max(relu2, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
outputs_fed_lstm2 = pooling2

x = tf.squeeze(outputs_fed_lstm2, [2])     
x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
x = tf.split(0, time_steps, x)

lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = _units)

# multi_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * lstm_layers, state_is_tuple = True)

outputs , state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm,x, dtype = tf.float32)     

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([_units,num_classes]))
biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

logits = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases



c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(c_loss)


global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
# decayed_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate,0,10000,0.9)
optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
minimize_loss = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)   
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,[conv_weights2]) 
correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for i in range(1):
         for j in range(1):
             x = train_set_x
             y = train_set_y
             sess.run(minimize_loss,feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
             step += 1  
             gr_print = sess.run([grad for grad, _ in grads_and_vars], feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
             print (gr_print)
             cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict = {X: x,Y: y})
             accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
             print ("Loss after one Epoch(Training) = " + "{:.6f}".format(cost) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(accu))
```

And here is the output

```
[array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  5.21326828,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]]], dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you compute is kind of weird. Let's examine the shapes in your model:

- input `x`: `[batch_size, 4, 2, 1]`
- 1st convolution `conv`: `[batch_size, 4, 1, 1000]`
- 1st max pool `pooling`: `[batch_size, 4, 1, 1]`
- 2nd convolution `conv2`: `[batch_size, 4, 1, 1000]`
- 2nd max pool `polling2`: `[batch_size, 4, 1, 1]`
- input to LSTM: `[4, batch_size, 1]`
- output of LSTM: `[batch_size, 500]`

---

From what I understand, you try to apply two 1D convolutions and then an LSTM. However, the first convolution is on the 3rd dimension of size `embedding=2`.

After that, you apply a max pooling on **all the 1000-sized embedding**. You should maybe apply the max pooling to the 2nd dimension of size 4:

```
pooling = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, [1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], "VALID")
# pooling has shape [batch_size, 2, 1, 1000]
```

---

Concerning your gradient issue, it comes from the two max pooling. Only 1 of the 1000 inputs is passed through, so the gradients for 999 of the inputs is 0.

This is why your first conv weights have only **2 non-zero gradients**, and the second conv weights have only **1 non-zero gradients**.

All in all, the real issue is your architecture here, you should maybe rewrite it down on a piece of paper first.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know where the problem is. I would definately up vote but I don't have enough rep! I'm trying to come up with a better model for NLP so that's why it's weird.

Comment: No problem! Often it's useful to analyze the shapes when debugging your model. A good rule is to try to keep the total dimension decreasing smoothly (here you make it go from 4000 to 4 and then to 4000)

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question, my network is like, input then 5 conv layers and then a RNN. My question is how can I overfit my network using only conv layers? Rest of the network will be same. Should I make my conv layers wider or should I add more conv layers to make it deeper? I think making conv layers deeper will only result in fewer parameters but making conv layers wider will result in overfitting? What you think? By widening the conv layer I mean adding more filters to it.

Comment: I tried both of them, but deep networks train faster and overfit the data better than wide networks.